# Area routing, why is the area name needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a project with 2 areas. Its does work but I am a newbie to this and I want to understand why.

I have an Area called LogonArea

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "LogonArea_default",
            "LogonArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Why is the 'LogonArea/' part needed? Shouldn't it be able to find the controller without it?

**When I tried removing it I could still reach controllers with that Area but strangely I couldn't reach other areas while on that page.**

If this is really necessary how could I mask it so the Area wasn't visible in the url?

thanks

Comment: Please see my update about specifying the area when you want to "leave" the area.

Comment: That worked. I did have the 'area = ' bit in the ActionLink but I think what I was doing is removing that when I removed the {area} segment from the route.
Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `/LoginArea/` from the area route registration, it will be able to find your controller (as long as you don't have any conflicting controller names such as HomeController in the main section and HomeController in the area).

It's mainly there for your convenience. If you have an Admin area, everything in your site will be accessible via /Admin/{controller}. It's mostly just an organizational thing.

```
public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Admin";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I created a single controller called `FooController` in this project, and I was able to go to the url `/Foo` to reach it without needing to go to `/Admin/Foo`

When you create a link to a controller outside of the area you need to specify which area it's in (or specify that there is no area):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Go Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)
```