# Glimpse doesn't work with Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, glimpse

I'm new to Asp.Net MVC, due to some issues I've been having with Routes I discovered Glimpse and thought I'd give it a go, but I couldn't get the Glimpse.axd config page up, constantly getting a HTTP 404.

I made a new project and tried that, it worked fine. Through trial and error I eventually found that the problem is in the AreaRegistration file for my areas, if I do this:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "SomeArea_default",
            "Area/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

It works, I can get to the page, but if I leave out the area part

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "SomeArea_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

then it doesn't.

I have previously asked whether that part was optional and I thought it was:
[Area routing, why is the area name needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290536/area-routing-why-is-the-area-name-needed/23292539#23292539)

I'm putting it back in to get things working, whats the actual reason behind this? Should that always be there or is this a Glimpse bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is actually normal behavior and has everything to do with the order in which routes are being registered.

Let me explain it, based on a green field project as the one you created to pinpoint the problem.

When you create a new MVC project and you add a `Test` area for instance, then you'll find the following types and methods inside your project:

1. A `TestAreaRegistration` class defined as:

   ```
   public class TestAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
   {
     public override string AreaName 
     {
       get { return "Test"; }
     }

     public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
     {
       context.MapRoute(
         "Test_default",
         "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
     }
   }
   ```
2. An `Application_Start` method inside your `global.asax` defined as:

   ```
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
     AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
     FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
     RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
     BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
   }
   ```
3. A `RouteConfig` class inside the `App_Start` folder defined as:

   ```
   public class RouteConfig
   {
     public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
     {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Now it is just a matter of reading through the startup code with regards to registering the routes for the application:

1. First the areas are being registered `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();`
2. That call will result in `TestAreaRegistration.RegisterArea(...)` being called which will register the route `Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}`
3. Then the call to `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)` will be made which will register the default `{controller}/{action}/{id}` route and also registers a route to ignore `.axd` requests.

**now it is important to keep in mind that first all routes defined by the `Test` area will be checked and then the ones defined by the `RouteConfig` in case it is not a `Test` area related route**

Now what does this mean when you request `/glimpse.axd` with this default setup ?

The route that will match is the route that is ignored inside the `RouteConfig` because the routes that will be handled by your `Test` area must start with `Test/` which is clearly not the case for `/glimpse.axd`

**but** if you remove the `Test/` part from the `Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}` route registration inside the `Test` area registration, then the route that will match the `/glimpse.axd` request will now be handled by the routes defined by the `Test` area as it will basically act as a catch all, and since it will not find a match a 404 is returned.

TL;DR

Now you can solve this in 2 ways:

1. Add `context.Routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` to the top of the `TestAreaRegistration.RegisterArea` method and the route will be ignored like it is in the *default* situation
2. Switch the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` with the `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)` so that the `RouteConfig` routes will be matched first

Personally I would go for option 1 as it has the least impact.

Comment: That all makes sense and I'll give it a try when I get into work later. The odd thing is when I tried to find the answer I found a few people who seemed to have the same problem but never saw this mentioned as a solution. One for the Troubleshooting page? 
The question being asked was "Why doesn't Glimpse.axd work on my existing project but works on a new standalone one?"